# How to get/update property of parent object from child object

Tags: c#, oop, user-controls

I have a class called Invoice

```
public Invoice() {
        this.ServiceId = 0;
        this.Sections = new List<Section>();            
    }
```

I have another class called Sections

```
public Section() {
        this.Items = new List<Item>();
    }
```

and yet another class called Item

```
public Item() {
        blah, blah;
    }
```

Now I am passing an object of Item into my windows user control, and I have the need to update the 'ServiceId' property located on my Invoice class.  My question is there a way to edit that property from my item object? and how would I go about doing that.

Other information of note is that none of my classes inherit from anything.  Meaning that Item does not inherit from Section and Section not from Inspection.  They are simply list collections.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Definitively can be done, but might be possible that you're doing that on the incorrect place at first sight. An `Item` wouldn't change anything from `Invoice` on my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this is through a hierarchical dependency injection. The `Section` class should have a constructor that requires an `Invoice` and a `Parent` or `ParentInvoice` property:

```
public Section() 
{
    this.Items = new List<Item>();

    public Invoice Parent { get; set; }

    public Section(Invoice parent) 
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

And likewise with the `Item`; it should require a `Section` as a parent. Then from any item you will be able to use

```
Invoice i = this.Parent.Parent;
```

You can create methods that will add the sections and items like so:

```
public Invoice()
{
    //....
    public Section AddSection()
    {
        var s = new Section(this);
        Sections.Add(s);
        return s;
    }
    //...
}
```